# Mower dies when cutting grass

Tags: lawn-mower

I have a Troy built mower with Briggs & Stratton engine mower starts and runs until I start mowing dies when I start cutting grass

Comment: What have you done to fix it?  How old is it?  Can we assume the grass is thick (providing a load on the engine)?  Combustion engines have three factors:  Fuel, Air, and Spark.  Checking the delivery of these three factors is where you start.  I always start with fuel (check gas level), air (clean the filter), then the plug (gap check and emery-paper it).  If these don't help, you can try to investigate fuel delivery, but beyond these, it's not usually worth much more time than you will have to put in to checking magnetos (depending on your mower), but this is easy to check too (see online).

Comment: Do you see any smoke when you are running?

Comment: Does the mower just shut off, or does it sputter and die? Is the grass really long? Has the mower ever worked? Are you holding down the safety lever while you mow?

Comment: Question is better suited for http://gardening.stackexchange.com.

Comment: likewise, can you specify if it stops running when you start the blades or when the blades have already started and they are now on grass?

Answer (score 0):

This might be as simple as the gas cap on the lawn mower needs to be cleaned.  Try running it with the gas cap "loose" and see if the same thing happens.